# Getting PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist in plsql function but not from the command view

Tags: plsql

i have function with a cursor the read the dba_scheduler_jobs which is a view. How can i use a view in a cursor?

```
create or replace function fn_gss_chk_scheduled_jobs(p_key IN varchar2)
  return boolean is
  --Result     boolean;
  failed_cnt number;
  stas       varchar2(20);
  check_type varchar2(50) := 'Scheduled Jobs';

  cursor c1 is

    select JOB_NAME, COMMENTS
      from dba_scheduler_jobs
     where owner = 'FCUBSPROD'
       AND state <> 'SCHEDULED'
       AND state <> 'RUNNING';

begin

  for rec in c1 loop

    IF c1%FOUND THEN
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line(Rec.Comments);
      stas := 'ERROR';
      pn_gss_update_dash_det(p_key, rec.job_name, rec.comments, 'D');

    ELSE

      stas := 'OK';
    END IF;
  end loop;

  pn_gss_update_dash_det(p_key, check_type, stas, 'S');

  return(true);
end fn_gss_chk_scheduled_jobs;
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: It was a rights issue. After granting the select it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant select on DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS TO the owner of the schema where the function resides.

The code needs the permission to be granted directly.

If you are running as user other than the one who owns the function you must also grant execute on fn_gss_chk_scheduled_jobs to  your_user;

Answer (score 3):

from sys user -->
grant select any dictionary to 'desired schema';